# C++ pointers to member functions

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers

I'd like to use a pointer to member function in C++, but it doesn't work:

pointer declaration:

```
int (MY_NAMESPACE::Number::*parse_function)(string, int);
```

pointer assignation:

```
parse_function = &MY_NAMESPACE::Number::parse_number;
```

This call works perfectly (itd is an iterator to elements of a map):

```
printf("%s\t%p\n",itd->first.c_str(),itd->second.parse_function);
```

But this one doesn't work:

```
int ret = (itd->second.*parse_function)(str, pts);
$ error: 'parse_function' was not declared in this scope
```

And this one neither

```
int ret = (itd->second.*(MY_NAMESPACE::Number::parse_function))(str, pts);
$ [location of declaration]: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'MY_NAMESPACE::Number::parse_function'
$ [location of the call]: error: from this location
```

I don't understant why ...

Thx in advance !!

Comment: Might be better to familiarise yourself with std::function

Comment: Please show the declaration of `parse_number` and of the container to which `itd` belongs.

Comment: the first call (in the printf) returns something coherent (there is a switch case where a parsing_function is affected to "parse_function" and. All the elements of the map<string,Number> that match case1 the printed result is 0x2ad9d65302e0 and all the elements that match case2 the printed result is 0x2ad9d65303b0.

Comment: Tried removing the asterisk in `int ret = (itd->second.*parse_function)(str, pts);` ?

Comment: Please post a complete example that shows your problem. With function pointers in C++, the devil is in the details and they become much more obvious to us if you post a complete example.

Comment: $ error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'itd.std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::operator-> [with _Tp = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, MY_NAMESPACE::Number>, std::_Rb_tree_iterator<_Tp>::pointer = std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, MY_NAMESPACE::Number>*]()->std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, MY_NAMESPACE::Number>::second.MY_NAMESPACE::Number::parse_function (...)'

Comment: Try using `->*` then, what happens? It is a pointer after all.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [usable example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: '->*' instead of '.*' doesn't change the error's message

Comment: question solved (see Olaf's post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int (MY_NAMESPACE::Number::*parse_function)(string, int);
```

This shows, `parse_function` is a pointer to a member function of class `Number`.

> This call works perfectly (itd is an iterator to elements of a map):

`printf("%s\t%p\n",itd->first.c_str(),itd->second.parse_function);`

and from this we can see `parse_function` is a member of `itd->second`, whatever this is.

For this call

```
int ret = (itd->second.*parse_function)(str, pts);
```

or this call

```
int ret = (itd->second.*(MY_NAMESPACE::Number::parse_function))(str, pts);
```

to succeed, `itd->second` must be of type `Number`, which it presumably isn't. And parse_function must be defined as either a variable in the current or enclosing scope (fist case) or a static variable of class Number (second case).

So you need some `Number` and apply `parse_function` to that

```
Number num;
(num.*(itd->second.parse_function))(str, pts);
```

or with a pointer

```
Number *pnum;
(pnum->*(itd->second.parse_function))(str, pts);
```

**Update**:

Since `itd->second` is a Number, you must apply `parse_function`, which is a **member** of it, like this

```
int ret = (itd->second.*(itd->second.parse_function))(str, pts);
```

Comment: `itd->second` must be of type `Number`... but it is!
`map<string, Number >::iterator itd = mapNumbers.begin();` Argh... I don't understand

Comment: @Jav Please include this *important* information in your question.

Comment: Thank you!!!! This works now! (omg:I haven't thaught about this but now it seems clear to me, txh)

Answer (score 0):

You can define pointers to functions like so: `type(*variable)() = &function;`
For example:

```
int(*func_ptr)();
func_ptr = &myFunction;
```

I might just not realize your code this early morning, but problem could be that `parse_function` is a pointer, yet you're calling it like `itd->second.*parse_function`.
Pointers are called with the `->*`, so try doing `itd->second->parse_function`.

Might not fix anything tho, I can't really seem to catch onto your code.
Posting more information, it's hard to tell from two lines of code.

---

Here's one example on how it's used in actual code, this one calls `func()` through `cb()` using pointers and parameters only:

```
int func()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}

void cb(int(*f)())
{
    f();
}

int main()
{
    int(*f)() = &func;
    cb(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you've missed a semicolon after `int(*f)() = &func` (sorry for nitpicking) :)

Comment: Pointer to function is very different from pointer to member function in C++. Read the question carefully